# I am not getting how to set the request for XML in WSDL service call

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
    I am integrating with third party vendor where they have exposed SOAP apis. I am having issue while creating the request.

    The below is WSDL generated code of vendor wsdl file.
```

Usually what we do is we create xml fields and then sent it, But in this case it has some XMLrequest where i need to set the request. I googled but didnt get the solution.

The below is WSDL generated code of vendor wsdl file.
Usually what we do is we create xml fields and then sent it, But in this case it has some XMLrequest where i need to set the request. I googled but didnt get the solution.

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "xmlRequest"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "GetAuthenticationToken")
    public class GetAuthenticationToken {

        protected GetAuthenticationToken.XmlRequest xmlRequest;

        public GetAuthenticationToken.XmlRequest getXmlRequest() {
            return xmlRequest;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "content"
        })
        public static class XmlRequest {

            @XmlMixed
            @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
            protected List<Object> content;


            public List<Object> getContent() {
                if (content == null) {
                    content = new ArrayList<Object>();
                }
                return this.content;
            }

        }

    }


    How do I set the XmlRequest which has request something like this.

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetAuthenticationToken>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:xmlRequest>
             <parent>
                 <A>ffd</A>
                 <B>57</B>
                 <C>2</C>
                 <D>12</D>
              </parent>
         </tem:xmlRequest>
      </tem:GetAuthenticationToken>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Please let me know if didn't understood the problem statement.
```

Comment: Are you saying that there is no setter in the class, so you can't `setXmlRequest`? If so, isn't object creation taken care of by some `ObjectFactory` in the same package? Otherwise, how did you generate the code?

Comment: Object factory is there. Authenticate.XmlRequest xmlRequest = objectFactory.createAuthenticateXmlRequest(); But how do i set XML request in this?    As per my understanding i need to call get content(It would return list) method then add the object. How do I set the Java pojo in to list of object?

Comment: Should you be creating a GetAuthenticationToken, e.g. `ObjectFactory.createAuthenticationToken()` which presumably is what you will be sending? I would expect that to create the nested xmlRequest, which would be accessible via the `GetAuthenticationToken.getXmlRequest()`

Comment: By creating i would get nested object reference. I have to add the xml data into that refernce but not getting in what format should add?

Comment: I understand your issue now - `content` is a list of `Object`s - you've been saying it, sorry I hadn't picked up on that sooner.
What is the (non-prefixed) root namespace of the WSDL? It will define what <parent> and its children are supposed to be. If they aren't defined in the WSDL itself, they should be defined in another schema file that you'll need to include when generating the code. Maybe the vendor can help with that?